# Setting LIBRARY_PATH for rocksdb in linux with clang/gcc

Tags: gcc, linker, clang, shared-libraries, rocksdb

I am trying to build rocksdb as a shared library and facing issues while specifying its dependencies. I want to compile rocksdb with bzip2 but the issue is by default rocksdb is using bzip2 shared library in my system directories but I want it to use the path in my LIBRARY_PATH. Is it due to priority? can I over come this? I also tried to compile a simple c program using gcc and clang with -v flag after doing export LIBRARY_PATH=/home/test

GCC output:

```bash
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --disable-libgcj --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.5-20150702/obj-x86_64-redhat-linux/cloog-install --enable-gnu-indirect-function --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=x86-64 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (GCC) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/cc1 -quiet -v temp.c -quiet -dumpbase temp.c -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -auxbase temp -version -o /tmp/cc0hqFLg.s
GNU C (GCC) version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (x86_64-redhat-linux)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36), GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.1, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../x86_64-redhat-linux/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
GNU C (GCC) version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36) (x86_64-redhat-linux)
    compiled by GNU C version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36), GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.1, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 592abcad67b46aec035d56e51f71d007
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v --64 -o /tmp/ccrqa76q.o /tmp/cc0hqFLg.s
GNU assembler version 2.27 (x86_64-redhat-linux) using BFD version version 2.27-34.base.el7
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/:/usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/:/lib/../lib64/:/usr/lib/../lib64/:/home/test/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/libexec/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/collect2 --build-id --no-add-needed --eh-frame-hdr --hash-style=gnu -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/home/test -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../.. /tmp/ccrqa76q.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
```

clang output:

```
clang version 3.4.2 (tags/RELEASE_34/dot2-final)
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2
Found candidate GCC installation: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5
 "/usr/bin/clang" -cc1 -triple x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu -emit-obj -mrelax-all -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name temp.c -mrelocation-model static -mdisable-fp-elim -fmath-errno -masm-verbose -mconstructor-aliases -munwind-tables -fuse-init-array -target-cpu x86-64 -target-linker-version 2.27 -v -resource-dir /usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.4.2 -internal-isystem /usr/local/include -internal-isystem /usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.4.2/include -internal-externc-isystem /include -internal-externc-isystem /usr/include -fdebug-compilation-dir /home/cstore -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 114 -mstackrealign -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -vectorize-slp -o /tmp/temp-d8b8da.o -x c temp.c
clang -cc1 version 3.4.2 based upon LLVM 3.4.2 default target x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
ignoring nonexistent directory "/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/bin/../lib/clang/3.4.2/include
 /usr/include
End of search list.
 "/usr/bin/ld" --hash-style=gnu --no-add-needed --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o a.out /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crt1.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crti.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crtbegin.o -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64 -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../.. -L/lib -L/usr/lib /tmp/temp-d8b8da.o -L/home/cstore -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/crtend.o /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/../../../../lib64/crtn.o
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Machine info with uname -a:
Linux 698324c876e6 6.5.11-linuxkit #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Dec  6 17:08:31 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

clang version: 3.4.2
gcc version:  4.8.5

**Edit-1**
After lot of googling and testing I found out that in linux LIBRARY_PATH is not searched first for shared library during compile time where as in mac os the path I set using LIBRARY_PATH will be used first. What is causing this behaviour. In linux the path which I set will be appened with ../lib and that path will be searched first and later some paths set by gcc and later my actual path.

Example:
$ export LIBRARY_PATH=/home/test
-> after compiling a program with -v I get the output as
LIBRARY_PATH=/home/test/../lib::/home/test:.

**Edit-2**
I am using rocksdb 5.8 version with make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For cmake users: Try setting `-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to your installation directory in your `cmake` command.

For RocksDB Makefile users: Try setting `EXTRA_CXXFLAGS="-I/path/to/your/custom/include/dir/" EXTRA_LDFLAGS="-L/path/to/your/custom/lib/dir"` in your RocksDB `make` command. Also, set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/your/custom/lib/dir` in your environment when running the binary. You can skip setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if you set rpath in the link step.

Comment: I am using make

Comment: ok, updated with the make commands I typically use